# how to remove repeated words from array

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to remove repeated (duplicate words) words from the array. I cannot figure out how to only print each word once but here is what I have so far. Here's my code:

```
 @foreach( App\Models\Images::where('status','active')->get() as $response )
   
    <?php
        $_tags = $response->tags;
        $tags = array_unique( explode(',', $_tags) );
        sort($tags); 
    ?>
    
    @foreach( $tags as $query )

        <?php $countTags = App\Models\Images::where( 'tags','LIKE', '%'.$query.'%' )->count(); ?>
        <url>
            @if( $countTags != 0 )
            <loc>{{ url('search?q=') }}{{ str_replace(' ', '+', $query) }}</loc>
                
        </url>
            @endif
    @endforeach 

 @endforeach
```

**i get repeated result:**

```
Array ( [0] => 1080p [1] => 2k [2] => 4k [3] => 4k wallpapers [4] => desktop wallpapers ) https://wallpaperaccess.in/search?q=1080p https://wallpaperaccess.in/search?q=2k https://wallpaperaccess.in/search?q=4k https://wallpaperaccess.in/search?q=4k+wallpapers https://wallpaperaccess.in/search?q=desktop+wallpapers Array ( [0] => 1080p [1] => 2k [2] => 4k [3] => 4k wallpapers [4] => desktop background [5] => desktop wallpapers ) https://wallpaperaccess.in/search?q=1080p https://wallpaperaccess.in/search?q=2k https://wallpaperaccess.in/search?q=4k https://wallpaperaccess.in/search?q=4k+wallpapers https://wallpaperaccess.in/search?q=desktop+background https://wallpaperaccess.in/search?q=desktop+wallpapers Array ( [0] => 1080p [1] => 2k [2] => 4k [3] => 4k wallpapers [4] => blue water [5] => desktop background [6] => desktop wallpapers [7] => mountain )
```

Comment: ``array_unique`` should work. What is the format of your ``$response->tags`` data?

Comment: in `$response->tags`  where `$response` table and `tags` is column in database.

Comment: Post the sample data that ``$response->tags`` has.

Comment: ok i posted sample data

Answer (score 0):

I used nested foreach loops based on the array values of the example of the question without commas, and I separated it with a space using `explode();` function.

```
$arr = Array();
$words = Array();
$_tags = Array("1080p", "2k", "4k", "4k wallpapers", "desktop wallpapers");
foreach($_tags as $key => $value) {
    $arr = explode(' ', $value);    
    foreach ($arr as $t) {
        $words[] = $t;
    }   
}
$tags = array_unique($words);
sort($tags);
print_r($tags);
```

Result:

```
Array ( [0] => 1080p [1] => 2k [2] => 4k [3] => desktop [4] => wallpapers )
```

Comment: in `$response->tags`  where `$response` is table and `tags` is column in database.

Comment: i try your code but it still gives me duplicate array

Comment: Can you post the `$response->tags` content in plain text?

Comment: I edited my answer based at the last array example.